# MySql Event scheduler is not running

Tags: mysql

Below is the Event which I have written to be executed every day. I ran the `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;` before creating the event still it excutes only first day but from next day onwards it will not run.

Is there anything wrong in this query?

```
DELIMITER $$
ALTER DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `Event1` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2017-03-15 00:00:00' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO CALL UpdateLeaves()$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
...ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE...
```

change to

```
...ON COMPLETION PRESERVE...
```